# Unable to get string values from .Resx file within Monodevelop on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, resources, mono, monodevelop, resx

From this question : 
[C#, Localization, Resources, and MonoDevelop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567964/c-localization-resources-and-monodevelop)
In the answers part it says :
"The usual thing is to store your resources in .resx form in the project, and MonoDevelop will automatically compile them into .resources files when building your project (you'd have to compile .txt files manually). Unfortunately MD doesn't have special editing tools for resx files, so you'd have to edit the XML directly."

I have a Application that works on Windows with vs2008.
I am trying to port it to Mac OSX.
I have a .resx file that contains different strings.
When I use:
Resources.Properties.Resources.Distributor_ARDL 
I get : 
    {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.OverflowException: Number overflow.   at (wrapper managed-to-native) object:__icall_wrapper_mono_array_new_specific (intptr,int)   at System.Drawing.Icon.InitFromStreamWithSize (System.IO.Stream stream, Int32 width, Int32 height) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Drawing.Icon..ctor (System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) [0x00000] in :0    at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in :0    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectRecord.LoadData (System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager manager, ISurrogateSelector selector, StreamingContext context) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups () [0x00000] in :0    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ReadNextObject (System.IO.BinaryReader reader) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ReadObjectGraph (BinaryElement elem, System.IO.BinaryReader reader, Boolean readHeaders, System.Object& result, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Header[]& headers) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.NoCheckDeserialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.HeaderHandler handler) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Resources.ResourceReader.ReadNonPredefinedValue (System.Type exp_type) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Resources.ResourceReader.ReadValueVer2 (Int32 type_index) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Resources.ResourceReader.LoadResourceValues (.ResourceCacheItem[] store) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Resources.ResourceReader+ResourceEnumerator.FillCache () [0x00000] in :0    at System.Resources.ResourceReader+ResourceEnumerator..ctor (System.Resources.ResourceReader readerToEnumerate) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Resources.ResourceReader.GetEnumerator () [0x00000] in :0    at System.Resources.ResourceSet.ReadResources () [0x00000] in :0    at System.Resources.ResourceSet.GetObjectInternal (System.String name, Boolean ignoreCase) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Resources.ResourceSet.GetObject (System.String name, Boolean ignoreCase) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Resources.RuntimeResourceSet.GetObject (System.String name, Boolean ignoreCase) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Resources.ResourceSet.GetStringInternal (System.String name, Boolean ignoreCase) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Resources.ResourceSet.GetString (System.String name, Boolean ignoreCase) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString (System.String name, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in :0    at Imaginality.Resources.Properties.Resources.get_Distributor_ARDL () [0x00000] in

So I am wondering if the resx file is working properly. 
If anyone else has had any luck with this problem. 
The build option for the resx is set to embeddedresouce.

Comment: This looks like a bug somewhere. Can you file it here: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com? Remember to add a complete test project.

Answer (score 0):

Hi after some mucking around I found that mono did not like a couple of .icon files I had created. As of this time I am not sure what it didnt like (as it did like 3 out of 8) so once I removed the files it built fine. It took a bit of time to see which they were as the error is not related to the icon files just the first call to the Resourced file.
Cheers